# Syntax error in multiple SELECT subqueries under AGGREGATE functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to use aggregate functions and inside them are subqueries. In my understanding of SQL construction. I came up with this. But it says syntax error. Can anybody help me reconstruct the statement? The original is so long with INNER JOIN clauses so I just removed them because the aggregate functions' part is just the part where it's going nuts. Thanks

```
SELECT CCompany,
       COUNT(SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE (CPaymentAmount<CFinalTotal and CStatus='Shipped')) as UnpaidTransactionCount,
       COUNT(SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE (CPaymentAmount=CFinalTotal and CStatus='Shipped')) as PaidTransactionCount,
       SUM(SELECT CFinalTotal FROM Table1 WHERE (CPaymentAmount<CFinalTotal and CStatus='Shipped')) as UnpaidTotal,
       SUM(SELECT CPaymentAmount FROM Table1 WHERE (CPaymentAmount<CFinalTotal and CStatus='Shipped')) as PartialPayment 
       FROM Table1 
       WHERE CStatus='Shipped'
```

It says syntax error near 'SELECT' and 'as'. Basically I'm trying to count transactions that are unpaid and paid, then sum up everything to get the balance. Balance is solved using my scripting language. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need:

```
SELECT CCompany,
   SUM(CASE WHEN CPaymentAmount<CFinalTotal THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as UnpaidTransactionCount,
   SUM(CASE WHEN CPaymentAmount=CFinalTotal THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as PaidTransactionCount,
   SUM(CASE WHEN CPaymentAmount<CFinalTotal THEN CFinalTotal ELSE 0 END) as UnpaidTotal,
   SUM(CASE WHEN CPaymentAmount<CFinalTotal THEN CPaymentAmount ELSE 0 END) as PartialPayment 
FROM Table1 
WHERE CStatus='Shipped'
GROUP BY CCompany
```

Unless there's some reason why you think the subqueries are needed. They all seem to be about the same table, and whilst your subqueries weren't correlated on `CCompany`, I've taken the liberty of expecting that you were wanting a per-company result.

If this isn't what you were aiming for, some sample data and expected results would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is exactly the thing I'm aiming for. Thank you Sir! Oh boy I'm so dumb when I saw your answer, I was like, why didn't I think of that? I had to think of something more complicated and it never made sense. One thing though, why do both COUNT functions return the same number? I only have 2 dummy rows in the database and 1 is fully paid and 1 is not. They both return 2. Why is this? It should return 1 and 1. Thanks.

Comment: @chris_techno25 - I misthought it. I've switched them to `SUM`s also.

Comment: @chris_techno25: COUNT could be used too, but you would need to change the `ELSE 0` to `ELSE NULL` (or remove the ELSE branch entirely).

Comment: @AndriyM - I did consider doing that to keep the `COUNT`, but then decided avoiding the `Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.` can be quite nice.

Comment: @AndriyM, Thank you for your help. I did just that and it works like a charm. Thank you both of you :)

Comment: Agree entirely, sparing someone extra confusion is always nice.

Answer (score 0):

The inner statement will give you  all columns as you mentioned select * statement. You can't use count with the result of inner query.

Check the statement.